# Unable to export the variable through script file

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to export a variables through myDeploy.sh but the export is not getting set. When i am echoing it is not echoing. However, when i set the variable explicitly on command it sets properly and echoes too.Below is the snippet of my code.

myDeploy.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash

# export the build root

export BUILD_ROOT=/tibco/data/GRISSOM2

export CUSTOM1=/tibco/data/GRISSOM2/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common/MDR_ITEM_E1/rulebase

export CLEANUP=$BUILD_ROOT/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common

cd $BUILD_ROOT/DEPLOYMENT_ARTIFACTS/common
```

When I echoes `echo $BUILD_ROOT` it is not echoing the path for me. But when I do it explicitly on command prompt like

```
[root@krog3-rhel5-64 GRISSOM2]# export BUILD_ROOT=/tibco/data/GRISSOM2
```

It sets properly and echoes too. What am I missing?

Comment: How are you calling the script? like `# ./myDeploy.sh` or like `# . myDeploy.sh`?

Comment: is your file permissions correct?

Comment: ./myDeploy.sh like this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running your script like

`. ./script`

or

`source script`

would execute your script in the current shell context (without creating a subshell) and the environment variables set within the script would be available in your *current* shell.

From the manual:

> . *filename* [*arguments*]
>
> Read and execute commands from the *filename* argument in the current
>   shell context. If *filename* does not contain a slash, the `PATH` variable
>   is used to find filename. When Bash is not in `POSIX` mode, the current
>   directory is searched if filename is not found in `$PATH`. If any
>   arguments are supplied, they become the positional parameters when
>   *filename* is executed. Otherwise the positional parameters are
>   unchanged. The return status is the exit status of the last command
>   executed, or zero if no commands are executed. If *filename* is not
>   found, or cannot be read, the return status is non-zero. This builtin
>   is equivalent to `source`.

Comment: **source** always works for me...

Comment: `source` is a synonym for `.`

Comment: @TheCodeArtist `source` is a Bash addition, while the dot (`.`) command is portable to every POSIX shell.  If you only learn one, learn the portable one.