# Can I change $PATH from a machine where I am not root

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a Red Hat Linux machine where I am not root.

In my home folder, I added this to my `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/path/to/my/directory:$PATH
```

Then, I ran `./.bash_profile` and `./.bashrc`.

However, `$PATH` is not updated.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: BTW, hopefully you're adding a *directory* as opposed to a file to PATH; adding the name of a file won't have any effect. And BTW, there's no need to use `export` there explicitly -- the `PATH` variable is already in the environment, so updates to it will be exported without any further action needed.

Comment: That's right a directory. I updated the question.

Comment: BTW, this is arguably duplicative of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17852111/unable-to-export-the-variable-through-script-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you *run* these files -- like when you conventionally execute any script -- they're executed in a separate shell, and changes to that shell's state (working directory, variables, etc) are lost when that shell exits. If the goal is to change the state of the interactive shell that you're operating in, you need to *source* them instead.

Syntax is as follows:

```
source .bashrc  # on extended shells such as bash only
. .bashrc       # or on any POSIX-compliant shell
```

The space is critical; `./.bashrc` would instead be trying to run `.bashrc` as an executable, with its own interpreter, whereas `. .bashrc` is using the `.` command documented at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18 to execute the contents of the file in your current interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to source your .bash_profile to get the changes in your current shell.

Comment: Duplicative, no? Overlapping a preexisting answer is fine, but you should try to have something you're adding that isn't covered elsewhere.

Comment: Your answer was not visible when I started composing my answer.